# Remove Duplicate Windows Entry In Grub2

Tags: 13.04, grub2

Hi there im quite new to Linux

I have problem with my grub

Windows entry show twice in the grub and probably in wrong partition

[image]

As you can see there is 2 entry for Windows 7

I can only boot to windows using loader on /dev/sda2

I think loader for windows should be on /dev/sda1, but the loader on it render black screen to me

I think i did something wrong with my windows and endup with this grub..

Is there a way to fix this? (remove duplicate entry and change it to /dev/sda1)

And here is my partition
[image]

Comment: This is because your first partition is primary partition and it is reserved for your Windows 7 restore. You've to format/delete this partition in order to remove it from grub, but it will then become useless. You'll not be able to restore your windows after that, if you get any errors in Windows.. You need to run `update` command again in order to remove the list actually..

Comment: Nowadays Windows has a 100MiB boot partition. It is normal. Looks the same way on my Win7/12.04 Dual Boot system. I would NOT remove it, you won't be able to boot Windows afterwards.

Comment: @SauravKumar so basically i cant remove the duplicate entry?

Comment: @mondjunge usually there is only 1 entry inside grub, apparently i have make something wrong with my grub cause last time i cant even boot to linux..if im not mistaken, i run Boot-repair and endup with this grub

Comment: Of-course you can remove.. If you'll get any trouble like you've mentioned before then again [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) would help you.. or try what @Mitch has suggested you..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing after installing 13.04 a couple of months ago, but for me both of the options boot just fine.

If you want to have only the working one in grub, I suggest you hide the faulty loader in grub. The easiest way to manage grub would be to use grub-customizer

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`