# Multiple boot options for Windows 8.1 along with Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I was a Windows 8.1 user. Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now I have both windows and Ubuntu. Both are running well without any issues. The problem is, while booting I can see two options for booting to Windows 8.1

*1. Boot to Windows 8.1 on sda1*

*2. Boot to windows 8.1 on sda2*

And both options are working as well. I don't know why there should be two options. How can I remove one? I tried Boot Repair, but no change. Need you guys to help me solve this.

Comment: This would probably be very complicated and risky to do due to the nature of the boot menu (called GRUB). Try reading [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html) and if you manage to get it to work (although it's probably safest just to leave it as it is) then post your answer to your own question and Accept it :)  'changing the order of menu entries or changing their titles may require making complex changes to shell scripts stored in /etc/grub.d/.'

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/360251/remove-duplicate-windows-entry-in-grub2